# ¿cómo convertir un objeto a un string?

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv

Tengo declaradas unas clases para ordenar los objetos y necesito escribir por cada linea un string como el ejemplo, teniendo en cuenta que el último ; *(punto y coma se elimina y también que puede tener todos los valores como no tenerlos)* ejemplo:

```
"1; NIF; 27/11/1985;SHA1; 5646dfb36fb456bd756dc8974"
```

Todo esto debido a que necesito generar un .csv de diferentes líneas entonces mi idea es hacer un foreach para escribir las diferentes lineas usando varias instancias de las clases que también son diferentes. El siguiente código es replicable y funciona, pero estoy seguro que existe una manera mucho mas decente de hacerlo.
* nota no puedo usar librerias.

```
namespace Pruebas
    {
        internal class Program
        {
            private static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                tipoRegistro16 tr16 = new tipoRegistro16
                {
                    codigo = "1204;",
                    total = "$1.200.000;"
                };
                tipoRegistro161 tr161 = new tipoRegistro161
                {
                    codigo = "0015;",
                    nombre = "PRINTERS SAS;",
                    baseGravable = ";",
                    porcentaje = "19;",
                    valor = "1.200.000;",
                    codigoUnidad = "20;",
                    unidad = "6;",
                    valorPorUnidad = "200.000;"
                };

                Console.WriteLine(tr16.codigo + tr16.total);
                Console.WriteLine(tr161.codigo + tr161.nombre + tr161.baseGravable + tr161.porcentaje + tr161.valor + tr161.codigoUnidad + tr161.unidad + tr161.valorPorUnidad);
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
    public class tipoRegistro16
    {
        public string codigo { get; set; }
        public string total { get; set; }

    }
    public class tipoRegistro161
    {
        public string codigo { get; set; }
        public string nombre { get; set; }
        public string baseGravable { get; set; }
        public string porcentaje { get; set; }
        public string valor { get; set; }
        public string codigoUnidad { get; set; }
        public string unidad { get; set; }
        public string valorPorUnidad { get; set; }

    }
```

Resultado esperado:

```
1204;$1.200.000
0015;PRINTERS SAS;;19;1.200.000;20;6;200.000
```

Comment: ¿Qué pasa si un valor intermedio no está presente? Por ejemplo ¿Qué pasa si no hay valor para `tipo` pero si lo hay para `id` y `fecha`?

Comment: debería quedar algo asi como 1;;TIC;17/02/2010;SHA1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si tienes un objeto y la idea es `serializar` a `csv` entonces usa una libreria como ser

[CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/)

de esta forma la clase se exporta directo

```
List<ipoRegistro11> datos = new List<ipoRegistro11>();
//generas los datos

using (var writer = new StreamWriter("file.csv"))
using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer))
{
    csv.WriteRecords(datos);
}
```

Tambien tienes el

[File Helpers](https://www.filehelpers.net/)

entonces a la clase le define el delimitador

```
[DelimitedRecord(";")]
class tipoRegistro11
{
    //propiedades
}
```

y exportas

```
var engine = new FileHelperEngine<tipoRegistro11>();

//aqui creas los datos
List<ipoRegistro11> datos = new List<ipoRegistro11>();

engine.WriteFile("Output.csv", datos);
```

como veras queda muy simple el codigo usando librerias

---

Sino puedes usar librerias entonces podrias generar lineas con el `string.Join()` y al final lo grabas en el archivo con `File.WriteAllLines()`

```
protected void lbtnGenerar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<tipoRegistro11> datos = new List<tipoRegistro11>();

    for(...)
    {
        // aqui generas los datos
        datos.Add(item);
    }


    List<string> lineas = new List<string>();
    foreach(var item in datos)
    {
        string[] temp = new string[] { tr11.id, tr11.tipo, tr11.fecha.ToString(), ... };
        string linea = string.Join(";", temp);

        lineas.Add(linea);
    }

    File.WriteAllLines("archivo.csv", lineas);

 }
```

Comment: es que no puedo usar librerias externas, es la primer regla del ejercicio.

Comment: edite la respuesta agregando una opcion sin librerias

Comment: disculpa a que hace referencia? datos.Add(item); que va dentro de item?

Comment: hace referencia a los datos que vas a exportar, por eso es una lista de `tipoRegistro11`, quizas tenerlo todo en el mismo evento click no tendria mucho sentido, se supone que la lista deberias ir cargandola en otra acciones y en el guardar solo iterarla para generar las lineas del string

Answer (score 0):

Si deseas obteniendo en Label1 el texto  "tipoRegistro11", es porque estas agregando la representación del objeto, obten los valores del objeto y de esta forma obtendrás el texto `1; NIF; 27/11/1985; SHA1; 5646dfb36fb456bd756dc8974`

Realiza lo siguiente:

```
 protected void lbtnGenerar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                tipoRegistro11 tr11 = new tipoRegistro11();
                tr11.id = "1;";
                tr11.tipo = "NIF;";
                tr11.fecha = "27/11/1985;";
                tr11.algoritmo = "SHA1;";
                tr11.cufe = "5646dfb36fb456bd756dc8974";
                //* Error string str = tr11.ToString();
                string str = tr11.id + " " + tr11.tipo + " " + tr11.fecha + " " + tr11.algoritmo + " " + tr11.cufe;
                Label1.Text = str.TrimEnd(';');

             }
```

Para el caso del for puedes realizar lo mismo  :

```
        List<tipoRegistro11> registros = new List<tipoRegistro11>();

        tipoRegistro11 tr11 = new tipoRegistro11();
        tr11.id = "1;";
        tr11.tipo = "NIF;";
        tr11.fecha = "27/11/1985";
        tr11.algoritmo = "SHA1";
        tr11.cufe = "5646dfb36fb456bd756dc8974";
        registros.Add(tr11); //Agrega objeto

        //string str = tr11.ToString();
        string str = tr11.id + " " + tr11.tipo + " " + tr11.fecha + " " + tr11.algoritmo + " " + tr11.cufe;

        Label1.Text = str.TrimEnd(';');



        foreach (var registro in registros)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(registro.id + " " + registro.tipo + " " + registro.fecha + " " + registro.algoritmo + " " + registro.cufe);
        }
```